# Running Kubernetes locally with non-administrative privileges and missing kubernetes config file

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

I am learning Kubernetes with Docker to launch a simple Python web application. I am new to all the above technologies.

Below is the approach I was planning on:

1. Install Kubernetes.
2. Have a cluster up and running locally.
3. Install Docker.
4. Create Python Application

I successfully installed Kubectl on my local using Chocolatey following instructions from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/.

I created `.\kube` directory in C:\Users directory. But I do not see any config files neither in the location where kubernetes has been installed `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools\kubernetes\client\bin` nor in `C:\Users\User1\.kube` directory.

When I run the command **".\kubectl cluster-info"** in powershell against C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools\kubernetes\client\bin
I get **"Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080"** response. But when I run the same command against C:\Users\User1.kube I get

> .\kubectl : The term '.\kubectl' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdle or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Am I doing it the wrong way or missing anything here?

This blog says https://blog.tekspace.io/install-kubernetes-cli-on-windows-10/ **"copy config file from Kubernetes master node to .kube folder"** but I dont see any config file!

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The blog you refer illustrates how to configure the CLI (Command Line Interface) on your Win10 computer, so that you can connect to a Kubernetes cluster.

The cluster is running on others machines. In the following picture you see a simplified schema.

[image]
You connect to the master through a CLI (kubectl), the master receives your commands and acts on the nodes.

I suggest to copy kubectl.exe into folder `C:\WINDOWS\system32` (which is in the `PATH` variable) so that you can type kubectl from whatever folder you are.

The config file the blog speaks about is on the Kubernetes master. 
It's not in your local machine. If you manage the machine on which the kube master runs, you need to connect (probably via `SSH`) and get the file (in `/etc/kubernetes/` - `admin.conf` or `kubernetes.conf`, it depends on the installation, I followed [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)).

Comment: Thanks, WIll try it out!

Comment: Apologize if this is a basic question but would like to understand it right! What do you mean by Kubernetes Master? Is it not the cluster which is running on my local? Appreciate your response.